# Pronunciation of the word "restaurant"

Tags: phonetics

How should the word "restaurant" be pronounced in BrE? Does the "t" in the end give a sound?I know that in Cambridge Dictionary "t" is written in the transcription, however, I heard the opinion that it can be silent in "restaurant".

Comment: The word was borrowed from the French, so it can be pronounced with a silent final 't' as it would be in French.

Comment: Wow, I have never heard that in use.  Where / in which English dialect is the terminal `-t` silent?

Comment: I think the big difference between most BrE dialects and American is that many of us tend to elide or semi-elide the middle vowel so that it is bisyllabic, wheres British speakers will generally pronounce the middle vowel, so the word has three syllables.  Of course there is variation per dialect, however.

Comment: @BadZen You ask in which dialect: I answer: in my dialect of BrE, namely RP, the final 't' in 'restaurant' is usually silent. Similarly, speakers of that dialect keep their cars in the 'garazh' not in the 'garridge'. Speakers of RP tend to be well educated and tend to want to show it. So if they know a word is French then they will try to indicate that in how they pronounce it. But  their education inevitably has its limits, so that when I, having lived in Prague, pronounce the brand of my car as 'shkoda', I am met with incomprehension.